# How to center a border

Tags: html, css, border, center, margins

I'm fairly new to CSS. I've been searching for answers about centering a div. I did looked some answers this site but it's doesn't help me very much. I want to have a perfect center. Thank you!

This is my image:

[image: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2na1k6u.jpg[/IMG]]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

@font-face {
    font-family: stonehen; src: url('stonehen.ttf'); }



    @font-face {
        font-family: stonehen src: url('stonehen.ttf'); 
        font-weight: bold; }
div {    
        border: 4px solid #A9A9A9;
        margin: auto;
        color: #A9A9A9;
        text-align: center;
        background: #006400;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 6px;
        font-family: stonehen, san-serif;
        font-size: 150%;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 300px; }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div> Welcome </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's centered properly: http://jsfiddle.net/6mhp49r3/

Comment: What's missing that leaves this an 'imperfect answer' to your problem?

Comment: Do you want it horizontally and vertically centered? If so checkout : http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: What is "perfect center"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center horizontally only...

```
div {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want it center BOTH horizontally and vertically you will need a fixed height and width to position it. Set the absolute positioning halfway along the x axis, and halfway along the y axis. Then "nudge" it back with negative margins that are half the width and half the height.

```
div {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height:100px;
  top 50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-50px; /*half of element height*/
  margin-left-150px; /*half of element width*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the end of your `div{}` and it will be perfectly centered:

```
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```